# Special output for wrong commands

Tags: errors, compilation-error

I'm curious if there is a way to make latex produce a specific output when a wrong command is entered, more specifically, say I have written \dfrak instead of \dfrac, is there a way I can make the compiler to, instead of not compiling, to compile and output a message like "Wrong command!" in the pdf?

Thanks

Comment: basically, no, this is not possible. Always check the log where errors are flagged.

Comment: If you see “wrong command” in the output you have little clues about where the wrong command was in the input.

Comment: If it's specific to `\dfrak`, you could define that command.  You can also compile in non-stop mode, so that you still get the errors, but tex guesses at the output you want.  But I don't think either of those is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Use the new Overleaf

Comment: @JohnSmith ? overleaf highlights errors in the source view, not in the pdf output, doesn't it?

Comment: If there are a limited number of mis-spelled commands, you might define them yourself. This may require using the correct number of arguments. Example: `\def\good#1{This is good.}` and `\def\goot#1{This is NOT good. Did you mean to command good instead?}